# PHP: What's wrong with this code, and why won't the variable increment?

Tags: php

```
$blogDir = 'blog/';
$blogdirHandle = opendir( $blogDir );
$checkingFile;
$number = 0;
$codeNumber = '-'.$number.'-';
if( $blogdirHandle = opendir( 'blog/' ) )
{
    while( ( $checkingFile = readdir( $blogdirHandle ) ) !== false ) 
    {
        if( $checkingFile != '.' && $checkingFile != '..' && !is_dir( $checkingFile ) && strpos( $checkingFile, $codeNumber ) !== false )
        {
            $number++;
        }
    }
    closedir( $blogdirHandle );
}
```

What I'm trying to do is:

Go through the $blogDir directory, and search for a file that has the same $codeNumber ( -$number- ), and if a file is found, then increase $number by one and search until all files are searched through. For some reason it's not working. It won't increase the value of $number, even though there are files with the same $codeNumber in the directory.. Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you increment `$number`, you need to re-assign `$codeNumber` inside your loop:

```
if( $blogdirHandle = opendir( 'blog/' ) )
{
    while( ( $checkingFile = readdir( $blogdirHandle ) ) !== false ) 
    {
        if( $checkingFile != '.' && $checkingFile != '..' && !is_dir( $checkingFile ) && strpos( $checkingFile, $codeNumber ) !== false )
        {
            $number++;
            $codeNumber = '-'.$number.'-';
        }
    }
    closedir( $blogdirHandle );
}
```

Comment: Yep. Thanks so much. I knew the answer was something stupidly simple like that, but I just couldn't put my finger on it.

Comment: By the way, there's also an issue with the call to is_dir(). You need to add the blog/ directory to it like this: !is_dir( $blogDir.$checkingFile ) - it's working anyway though, because if the file doesn't exist it returns false.

Comment: might make sense to put `$codeNumber = '-'.$number.'-';` at the beginning of the while, instead of outside, or in the if